# Links postbacks to the same page?

Tags: telerik, postback

I have multiple links on my page, when i click on any link, it first loads the same page using get or post and then go to the clicked url. I want to avoid the postback to the same url, what can be done?
Note, My application uses Telerik controls.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely going to depend on which Telerik controls you are using but the general rule of thumb would be to use the `OnClientClicking` (see [Telerik Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-onclientclicking.html)) using `set_cancel(true);` to prevent a postback.

If your links aren't telerik controls you could use javascript or JQuery (if being used) to cancel the postback using the `onclick` event and `return false;` to cancel the postback.